# Oauth2 without server or with AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda

I am trying to design an web application that will query data from Fitbit via its APIs and display it in different forms to the user. All this data functionality is implemented in Javascript and is executed on the client side (ie. in the browser) - there is no need for a backend or storage.

I am struggling however with the authentication. Fitbit provides Oauth2 and I have the following questions:

1. Must I have a server-side component (that offers a callback) or is it perhaps possible to handle it fully on the client side?
2. If there is a need for this server-side only for Fitbit's Ouath, does anyone has an example for doing it in AWS Lambda? I guess I would need only two functions: one for initiating the authentication and one for the callback. I am not sure however where/how to store the tokens and how to manage the user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform oAuth authorization on the client side (JS) without any server side code using Implicit flow.

However there are few differences between server side implementation (Authorization Code flow) and client side implementaiton(Implicit flow). Specific details relevant to Fitbit-Implicit flow is listed [here](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/#implicit-grant-flow)

You can use one of many oAuth2 client-side libraries to perform token exchange. I prefer using the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) for oAuth2 token exchange (and for OIDC client side implementation)